# How can i record and playback sound with WaveOut\waveIn Api

Tags: c#, c++, windows, audio, winmm

I need to record and playback sound. But in my company we have DLL for our special sound card. This dll working with api, that similar with waveIn\waveOut api. For example, if I need `waveOutOpen` function, I'm writing `companyNameWaveOutOpen`. And I need to write program that record and playback sound(ring). Please help me, how can i record and playback sound with WaveOut\WaveIn API. If you can help me, give me example in C++ or C#/VB.NET. 
added
i need to listen in speakers sound that provided by microphone.

Answer (score 1):

`waveInXxx`/`waveOutXxx` is old API and there are a lot of samples online. A simple playback code can be found here [LowLatencyWaveOutPlay](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/LowLatencyWaveOutPlay) and also discussed on this Q: [What is the smallest audio buffer needed to produce Tone sound without distotions with WaveOUT API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293749/what-is-the-smallest-audio-buffer-needed-to-produce-tone-sound-without-distotion).

Windows SDK contains:

- \Samples\multimedia\windowsmediaformat\audioplayer - sample using  `waveOutXxx` API
- \Samples\multimedia\audio\DuckingCaptureSample - sample using `waveInXxx` API.

You can use open source [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) as a wrapper over this API, and also check the implementation there.